# How do I generate a random timestamp in the next 5 days in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'd like to get a random time between 8am-3pm on any of the next 5 days in Python. I've tried playing around with timedelta on `date.now()`, but my results are never particularly random (I repeatedly get the same date, which leads me to think timedelta doesn't play so well with random)

Comment: post your code,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
today_random_time_between_8_and_3 = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=randint(8,14),minute=randint(0,59))
random_day =  today_random_time_between_8_and_3  + datetime.timedelta(days=random.randint(0,5))
print(random_day)
```

this picks a random hour between 8am and 2pm ... then adds random minutes between 0 and 59

lastly it just picks a random number between 1 and 4 and adds that many days to todays random time

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) + \
    timedelta(days=random.randint(1, 6), hours=8, seconds=random.randint(0, 60*60*7))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the next five days starts from tomorrow you could randomly select a number from 1 to 5 and add it to the current date.  Then combine it with a `time` object to create a `datetime` to which you can add a randomly selected number from 1 to 25200 (the number of seconds between 8AM and 3PM).

```
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta
from random import randint

d = date.today() + timedelta(days=randint(1, 5))
t = time(8, 0, 0)
dt = datetime.combine(d, t) + timedelta(seconds=randint(1, 25200))

print(dt)
```

If the next five days start today adjust the first `randint` to `randint(0, 4)`, and if your timestamp needs to include microseconds increase the second `randint`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach. Using `Datetime module` & `random` module

**Demo:**

```
import datetime
import random

def generateRandomDateTime():
    today  = datetime.datetime.now()
    dates = [(today + datetime.timedelta(days=i))for i in range(0, 5)]
    t = datetime.time(hour=random.randint(8, 15), minute=random.randint(0, 59), second=random.randint(0, 59))
    random_date = random.choice(dates)
    return datetime.datetime.combine(random_date, t)

print(generateRandomDateTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a starting timestamp that is at 8 AM tomorrow morning. Then generate a random number of seconds to add to this offset that would fall anywhere between 8AM and 3PM (7 hour window) - this sets the time of day, call it `time_offset`. Next pick a random number between 0 and 4 (inclusive) to pick the random day- call it `day_offset`. Finally add the `time_offset` in seconds and the `day_offset` in days to get the random timestamp.

For example:

```
import numpy
import datetime

def get_random_timestamp():
    start_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(1)   # tomorrow
    start_date = start_date.replace(hour = 8, minute=0, second=0)  # set to 8 AM
    seconds_max = 7*70*60  # 8AM to 3PM is 7 hours                 # 7 hrs in seconds
    time_offset = np.random.randint(0, seconds_max)
    day_offset = np.random.choice(range(5))
    final_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_offset, days=day_offset)
    return final_date

for i in range(10):
    print(datetime.datetime.strftime(get_random_timestamp(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
#2018-05-13 10:30:29
#2018-05-12 10:07:25
#2018-05-15 15:47:25
#2018-05-11 11:34:41
#2018-05-15 08:07:40
#2018-05-14 10:57:46
#2018-05-12 13:37:52
#2018-05-11 10:22:14
#2018-05-14 09:51:24
#2018-05-13 13:22:21
```